# Text not fitting the width of container

Tags: css, sizetofit

This looks like it would be a simple problem but I can't get my head around it. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzbTD.png), the text uses the width of the container, but when I change the width of the container, the text fits but it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au038.png) and pushes the sidebar down.

```
   .container {
        width:1130px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .container.sp_sidebar {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #main {
        width:100%;
    } 
    .container.sp_sidebar #main {
        width:770px;
        margin-right:30px;
        float:left;
    }
    #sidebar {
        width:300px;
        float:right;
    }
```

I've tried to float the container left, and also remove margin 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a space in that monstrous word.

Or add `word-break: break-all;` ([docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)) to your CSS.

Comment: Although improved, w3schools is still a crappy reference. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need some white spaces to break to another line (as in a common text). Next time, try to use some [Lorem Ipsum](http://br.lipsum.com/) text as placeholder.